# Is it bad practice to pass exception as argument to a method in java

Tags: java, exception

I have a method that should rollback if an exception occurs in a service. In the exception block, the rollback service throws an exception when it fails. I created a service for rollback but i pass exception as argument to second method. is that bad practice?

```
public static void method1() {
    try{
       //do something that can throw exception
    } catch (Exception e) {
         method2(data, e);
      }
}

public static void method2(String data, CustomException ce) {
    try{
     // rollback service that could fail
    } catch(Exception e) {
        log.warn("rollback failed!!!");
         ce.addSuppressed(e);
      }
 }
```

Comment: "is that bad practice?" No.

Comment: The only reason I asked was because I was told by some one to not do this and asked to just put it everywhere the rollback needed to happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of the day, `Exception`s are normal Java objects with the added property that they can be thrown. If we were to deny `Exception`s as parameters, it would take away the ability to, for example, have centralized handler-methods for `Exception`s (a concept found, for example, in [JavaEE's `ExceptionMapper`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/ext/ExceptionMapper.html)). If we were to deny the use of `Exception`s as parameters, we would most probably violate the [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) and most probably the [Separation of Concerns principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns). Both of which could lead to harder to read and maintain code.

Furthermore, if one of our method accepts `Object` (or `Object...` or `Collection<Object>`, ...) as parameter, we are not able to prevent that maybe an `Exception` is passed as parameter.

In conclusion, I see no reason why it should be a bad practice to pass an `Exception` as method parameter.